# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string inC:\xampp\htdocs\Amazing_World_Site\admin\index.php on line 70

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

$sql_post="SELECT COUNT(p_id) FROM tbl_posts";

$post_results=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql_post);

$post_numbers = $post_results."";
```

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string inC:\xampp\htdocs\Amazing_World_Site\admin\index.php on line 70

Line 70 `$post_numbers = $post_results."";`

How do you fix this error?

Comment: $post_results it is not a string, so you cann't concat to it .""

Comment: How can we concatenate into a string?

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query` will return an **object**, not a **string**.

You can get the row using this if you want to get only one column.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($post_results);
$post_numbers = $row['column_name'];
```

Replace `column_name` with your actual column name. Then, you can concat `$post_numbers` with whatever you want.

If you want to get more columns, you can use a `while` loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($post_results)) {
    $variable1 = $row['column_name'];
    $variable2 = $row['column2_name'];
}
```

`mysqli_query` Return Values (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.